# Unable to change 'animation-duration' CSS on body with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have a CSS animation running on the body element, which has a default duration of 20s.  I want this to be able to be changed through user input, but I can't seem to get it working.

The default CSS I have is:

```
body {    
    ...    
    animation: MoveBG 20s ease infinite;
}
```

If I run this jQuery code:

```
$('body').css('animation', 'MoveBG 2s ease infinite');
```

The animation will still have a 20s duration.  The funny thing is that if I run:

```
alert($('body').css('animation-duration'));
```

It will tell me that the animation duration is 2s (which it clearly isn't).

```js
// the animation duration should change to 2s, but it still animates at 20s
var animation = 'MoveBG 2s ease infinite';
$('body').css('animation', animation);

// it even says that it is animate at 2s
//alert($('body').css('animation-duration'));
```

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #f00, #0f0, #00f);
  background-size: 600% 100%;
  -webkit-animation: MoveBG 20s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: MoveBG 20s ease infinite;
  -o-animation: MoveBG 20s ease infinite;
  animation: MoveBG 20s ease infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes MoveBG {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 0
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0 0
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes MoveBG {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 0
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0 0
  }
}

@-o-keyframes MoveBG {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 0
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0 0
  }
}

@keyframes MoveBG {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 0
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0 0
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sdobc5vx/2/

Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

This is happening to me in Chrome 37 - but it looks like it's working in Firefox 30.  Hmm...

Comment: This doesn't work for me either.  Besides, I'm pretty sure that jQuery adds the vendor prefixes automatically now.

Comment: Seems like a frame refresh issue. If you hide and show frame refreshes. `$('body').css('animation', animation).hide().show(0);` http://jsfiddle.net/a5nv1hq3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly sure, but it looks like the frame refresh is not happening even if you override the already started keyframe, possibly a chrome bug.

One trick is to hide and element and show it (asynchronously) for repaint to happen (But not so desirable with flicker).

```
   $('body').css('animation', animation).hide().show(0);
                                                   //^__ Need this to force asyncronous show
```

```js
var animation  = 'MoveBG 2s ease infinite';
$('body').css('animation', animation).hide().show(0); 
                                                //^___Asyncronously show
```

```css
body {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #f00, #0f0, #00f);
    background-size: 600% 100%;
    -webkit-animation: MoveBG 20s ease infinite;
    -moz-animation: MoveBG 20s ease infinite;
    -o-animation: MoveBG 20s ease infinite;
    animation: MoveBG 20s ease infinite;
    
}


@-webkit-keyframes MoveBG {
 0%{background-position:0 0}
 50%{background-position:100% 0}
 100%{background-position:0 0}
}

@-moz-keyframes MoveBG {
 0%{background-position:0 0}
 50%{background-position:100% 0}
 100%{background-position:0 0}
}
@-o-keyframes MoveBG {
 0%{background-position:0 0}
 50%{background-position:100% 0}
 100%{background-position:0 0}
}
@keyframes MoveBG { 
 0%{background-position:0 0}
 50%{background-position:100% 0}
 100%{background-position:0 0}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
</body>
```

Here is another hack that works. Reset the animation to none and then set it back again, which really doesn't give a flicker.

```
var animation  = 'MoveBG 2s ease infinite';
var $body = $('body').css('animation', 'none'); //reset it
setTimeout(function(){
    $body.css('animation', animation); //set it back
});
```

**[Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/hpxgoffp/)**

You could use the same hack with addClass as well.

Comment: @DiscoInfiltrator You are welcome.. :) I would really like to know the actual cause of this issue though..  :(

Comment: Yeah, for sure.  I'm going to look into submitting a bug report for it.

Comment: @DiscoInfiltrator i even tried with hardware acceleration (translate3d) which ofcourse is not needed for desktop browser, boosts mobile animation performance. But no luck with that too..

Answer (score 1):

Edit,  Updated

Try (workaround)

```
var duration = "2s";
$("body")[0].style.WebkitAnimationDuration = duration;
$("style").detach().hide(function() {
  $("head").prepend(this);
});
```

```js
$(function() {
var twenty = $(".twenty");
var two = $(".two");
var span = $("span");
    span.prepend("<b>twenty: </b>" 
                + window.getComputedStyle(twenty[0], null).WebkitAnimation 
                + " <b>before</b>" 
                + "<br><b>two: </b>" 
                + window.getComputedStyle(two[0], null).WebkitAnimation 
                + "<b> before</b>");
// the animation duration should change to 2s, but it still animates at 20s
var duration  =  "2s";
// $('body').css('animation', animation);
two[0].style.WebkitAnimationDuration = duration;
$("style").detach().hide(function() {
  $("head").prepend(this);
});
span.append("<br><b>twenty: </b>" 
           + window.getComputedStyle(twenty[0], null).WebkitAnimation 
           + " <b>after</b>" 
           + "<br><b>two: </b>" 
           + window.getComputedStyle(two[0], null).WebkitAnimation 
           + "<b> after</b>");
// it even says that it is animate at 2s
alert(two.css('animation-duration') 
     + "\n" 
     + window.getComputedStyle(two[0], null).webkitAnimationDuration);
});
```

```css
span {
    font-size : 12px;
    height : 50px !important;
}
div.two {
    margin-left:20px;
}

div {
    display : inline-block;
    position : relative;
    width : 200px;
    height : 400px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #f00, #0f0, #00f);
    background-size: 600% 100%;
    -webkit-animation: MoveBG 20s ease infinite;
    -moz-animation: MoveBG 20s ease infinite;
    -o-animation: MoveBG 20s ease infinite;
    animation: MoveBG 20s ease infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes MoveBG {
 0%{background-position:0 0}
 50%{background-position:100% 0}
 100%{background-position:0 0}
}

@-moz-keyframes MoveBG {
 0%{background-position:0 0}
 50%{background-position:100% 0}
 100%{background-position:0 0}
}
@-o-keyframes MoveBG {
 0%{background-position:0 0}
 50%{background-position:100% 0}
 100%{background-position:0 0}
}
@keyframes MoveBG { 
 0%{background-position:0 0}
 50%{background-position:100% 0}
 100%{background-position:0 0}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <span class="animations"></span><br />
    <div class="twenty"></div><div class="two"></div>
</body>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sdobc5vx/31/

Comment: Unfortunately what you have is what exactly OP's example has as well. It ignores 2s animation duration.

Comment: Appear to reset at chrome 37 unstable. Difficult to view with background as linear-gradient. Composing side-by-side piece to confirm. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've tried it on Safari works just fine. Chrome is not responding to anything.

Try doing this, see if will make any difference:

```js
$('body').css({
    -webkit-animation: animation,
    -moz-animation: animation,
    -o-animation: animation,
    animation: animation,
});
```